# Flutter unit testing firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, mockito

I'm new to unit testing in general. I'm trying to test simple method from my DataRepository.

Following this link but seems deprecated: https://utkarshkore.medium.com/writing-unit-tests-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-72f99be85737

```
class DataRepository {
  final CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes');

  //Retour de models a la place de snapshots
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStream() {
    return collection.snapshots();
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStreamDetail(String id) {
    return collection.doc(id).collection('tasks').snapshots();
  }

  Stream<List<Note>> noteStream() {
    final CollectionReference collection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes');

    try {
      return collection.snapshots().map((notes) {
        final List<Note> notesFromFirestore = <Note>[];
        for (var doc in notes.docs) {
          notesFromFirestore.add(Note.fromSnapshot(doc));
        }
        return notesFromFirestore;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

So far this is what my test file look like:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockFirestore extends Mock implements FirebaseFirestore {}
class MockCollectionReference extends Mock implements CollectionReference {}

void main() {
  MockFirestore instance = MockFirestore();
  MockCollectionReference mockCollectionReference = MockCollectionReference();

  test('should return data when the call to remote source is succesful.',
      () async {
    when(instance.collection('notes')).thenReturn(mockCollectionReference);
  });
}
```

First instance throw me this error

```
The argument type 'MockCollectionReference' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>>'
```

I would really appreciate the help for testing the method.

new edit:

```
void main() {
  test('should return data when the call to remote source is succesful.',
      () async {
    final FakeFirebaseFirestore fakeFirebaseFirestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
    final DataRepository dataRepository = DataRepository();
    final CollectionReference mockCollectionReference =
        fakeFirebaseFirestore.collection(dataRepository.collection.path);

    final List<Note> mockNoteList = <Note>[];

    for (Note mockNote in mockNoteList) {
      await mockCollectionReference.add(mockNote.toJson());
    }

    final Stream<List<Note>> noteStreamFromRepository =
        dataRepository.noteStream();

    final List<Note> actualNoteList = await noteStreamFromRepository.first;
    final List<Note> expectedNoteList = mockNoteList;

    expect(actualNoteList, expectedNoteList);
  });
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use [**mocktail package**](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) for mocking dependencies?

Comment: Please include more code specifically the `DataRepository` class and the `Note` class. I've also added an answer below with the information you have up there.

Comment: Hi @WilliKim, please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [fake_cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_cloud_firestore) to mock the Firestore instance by using it's `FakeCloudFirestore` object that can be used in the place of an actual `FirebaseFirestore` object.

### An Example:

```dart
 import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
 import 'package:fake_cloud_firestore/fake_cloud_firestore.dart';

 test('noteStream returns Stream containing List of Note objects', () async {
      //Define parameters and objects

      final FakeFirebaseFirestore fakeFirebaseFirestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();

      final DataRepository dataRepository =
          DataRepository(firestore: fakeFirebaseFirestore);

      final CollectionReference mockCollectionReference =
          fakeFirebaseFirestore.collection(dataRepository.collection.path);

      final List<Note> mockNoteList = [Note()];

      // Add data to mock Firestore collection
      for (Note mockNote in mockNoteList) {
        await mockCollectionReference.add(mockNote.toSnapshot());
      }

      // Get data from DataRepository's noteStream i.e the method being tested
      final Stream<List<Note>> noteStreamFromRepository =
          dataRepository.noteStream();

      final List<Note> actualNoteList = await noteStreamFromRepository.first;

      final List<Note> expectedNoteList = mockNoteList;

      // Assert that the actual data matches the expected data
      expect(actualNoteList, expectedNoteList);
    });
```

### Explanation:

The test above makes the following assumptions about your code:

- You pass the `FirebaseFirestore` object into the `DataRepository` object.
- You have a `toSnapshot` method on your `Note` object which converts your `Note` object into a `Map<String, dynamic>` object.

The test works into the following way:

1. It creates the necessary objects needed for the test i.e the `FakeFirebaseFirestore` object, the `DataRepository` object, the mock `CollectionReference` object and the mock data to be passed into the mock collection reference (`mockNoteList`).
2. It adds the data into the mock collection reference.
3. It gets the data using the `DataRepository`'s `noteStream` method.
4. It asserts that the actual data from the `DataRepository` is equal to the expected data i.e the data passed originally into the mock collection reference.

### Resources:

For more understanding on unit testing Firestore in Flutter, check out the following resources:

- [FlutterFire's Documentation on Testing](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/testing/testing/), an overview on how to use the `fake_cloud_firestore` package in widget tests in Flutter.
- [Mocking and Testing Firestore Operations in Flutter Unit Tests | Part 1 (Documents and Collections)](https://blog.victoreronmosele.com/mocking-firestore-flutter), an article about using the `fake_cloud_firestore` package to test Firestore operations in Flutter Unit Tests, written by me.

### Update

Add the FirebaseFirestore object as one of your constructor parameters and use that instead of `FirebaseFirestore.instance`.

Update your `DataRepository` to this below:

```
class DataRepository {
  DataRepository({required this.firestore});

  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

   CollectionReference get collection =>
     firestore.collection('notes');

  //Retour de models a la place de snapshots
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStream() {
    return collection.snapshots();
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getStreamDetail(String id) {
    return collection.doc(id).collection('tasks').snapshots();
  }

  Stream<List<Note>> noteStream() {
    try {
      return collection.snapshots().map((notes) {
        final List<Note> notesFromFirestore = <Note>[];
        for (var doc in notes.docs) {
          notesFromFirestore.add(Note.fromSnapshot(doc));
        }
        return notesFromFirestore;
      });
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

*Updated DataRepository Usage:*

- In tests:

```dart
 final FakeFirebaseFirestore fakeFirebaseFirestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
 final DataRepository dataRepository =
          DataRepository(firestore: fakeFirebaseFirestore);
```

- In the app:

```dart
 final FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 final DataRepository dataRepository =
          DataRepository(firestore: firebaseFirestore);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer my DataRepository just have a instance like this
class DataRepository {
  final CollectionReference collection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('notes');
and like you guessed I have a map snapshot

Comment: Can you tell me why you use FakeCloudFirestore ? What does it add more than mockito only ?

Comment: @WillyKim, I used `FakeCloudFirestore` instead of `mockito` because it already implements the methods/operations that `FirebaseFirestore` supports and you can easily mock the state of the database by adding data to it like you would do with the `FirebaseFirestore` object.

Comment: Do you need more help with the question?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply thank you for the explanation just one last thing I get this error when I start the test: Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp(), I tried to add await Firebase.initializeApp() in the test method but still didn't work, any idea on how to solve this ?

Comment: You're getting that error most likely because you're still using the `FirebaseFirestore` object when you should be using `FakeFirebaseFirestore`. Please share the test code.

Comment: I think it is because I'm not instantiating DataRepository with firestore but i'm not sure i'm editing my question so you can see the test code.

Comment: @WillyKim, I have added an update to my answer on how you'll go about it.

Comment: Thank you @VictorEronmosele for the excellent answer. I have one question. Why pass in Firestore v. Firestore.instance?

Comment: @BillTurner the Firestore instance is passed to be able to use a mocked version of Firestore in tests. `FirebaseFirestore.instance` is the "real" Firestore object used in the app while `FakeFirestore()` is the mock version that allows you add data to it in tests.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your problem:
Specify a type for CollectionReference. This way:

```
class MockCollectionReference extends Mock implements CollectionReference<Map<String, dynamic>> {}
```